# Nested Json String to Pojo Mapping( I am able to map simple json to Pojo but unable to Map Nested Json)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, gson

`{"fullname": "Darla Kertzmann","address": {"street": "4519 Mraz Point","city": {                    "cityName":"Melbourne","cityCode":"0000"}}}`

This is a Mock json im working with. This json string is stored in my cassandra db. I am able to map simple json such as

`{"name":"Dan","pass":"123" }`

these are the classes

```
`@Data
public class Response{
//fullname mock here
    
@JsonProperty("address")
private Address address;
}`
```

```
`@Data
public class Address{
@JsonProperty("street")
private String street;

@JsonProperty("city")
private City city;
}`
```

```
`@Data
public class City{

@JsonProperty("cityName")
private String cityName;
    
@JsonProperty("cityCode")
private String cityCode;
}`
```

```
`ObjectMapper objMap = new ObjectMapper(); 
Response resp = new Response(); 
resp = objMap.readValue("jsonString",Response.class);`
```

Please Let me know where i am Wrong
I am not getting any error. Just that the values are returning null.
Tried JSONObject and to decrease one nested loop, Tried Gson

Comment: *"Just that the values are returning null"* - You mean all the fields are null? Can you print the object on the console and post it (don't forget that you need to override `toString()` method for it to be properly displayed.

Comment: *//fullname mock here* - what do you mean by *mock*, you're expected to a `String` field `fullname`?

Answer (score 0):

what is `//fullname mock here`?
its working

```java
package com.example.springdatademo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import lombok.Data;

@SpringBootTest
public class JsonTest {

  @Test
  void readValue() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objMap = new ObjectMapper();
    Response resp = objMap.readValue("{\"fullname\": \"Darla Kertzmann\",\"address\": {\"street\": \"4519 Mraz Point\",\"city\": {                    \"cityName\":\"Melbourne\",\"cityCode\":\"0000\"}}}", Response.class);
    System.out.println(resp);
  }
}

@Data
class Response {
  //fullname mock here
  @JsonProperty("fullname")
  private String fullname;

  @JsonProperty("address")
  private Address address;
}

@Data
class Address {
  @JsonProperty("street")
  private String street;

  @JsonProperty("city")
  private City city;
}

@Data
class City {

  @JsonProperty("cityName")
  private String cityName;

  @JsonProperty("cityCode")
  private String cityCode;
}
```

Comment: Full name is what you have added(String fullname). This should work but apparently Jackson is not mapping nested json for me.